# How to add day headers in JavaFX GridPane

Tags: java, javafx

This is the goal of the program.

[image]

The picture attached is the goal.  I am having trouble getting the day headers.  I have to use 2 methods that are called by the constructor.  buildUI and customizeUI.  I have tried using a for loop and I couldnt figure out the spacing.  When I ran it all the day headers were just on top of each other.

```
    Label[] a = {
                   new Label("S"), new Label("M"), 
                   new Label("T"), new Label("W"), 
                   new Label("T"), new Label("F"), 
                   new Label("S")
                 };

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {  
        p.getChildren().add(a[i]);
    }


    setCenter(p);
```

Comment: I don't know if I really got what you want to do, but if I understand correctly, you want to add those labels in a specific position to the gridpane right?

Answer (score 2):

```
Label[] a = {
               new Label("S"), new Label("M"), 
               new Label("T"), new Label("W"), 
               new Label("T"), new Label("F"), 
               new Label("S")
             };

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {  
    p.add(a[i], i, 0);
}

setCenter(p);
```

This should work. I guess `p` is a variable for `GridPane`. Here `p.add(a[i], i, 0);` I am adding labels according column and row index. Take a look at [`GridPane` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)